# PHP Manager - installation failed due to 32-bit processor

Tags: php, iis-10

I am having a 32-bit processor x86 having 32-bit  Windows 10 OS Notebook Laptop and I was trying to install PHP manager for IIS-10.

But, the installation file for PHP manager that I am getting from Microsoft or from GitHub is not compatible with my processor type i.e. 32-bit processor.

I tried all the available installation file options but all in vain.

For most recent version i.e. PHP Manager for IIS-10, it is showing "This installation package is not supported by this processor type error".
[This installation package is not supported by this processor type error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt6WZ.jpg)

For older version i.e. PHP Manager for IIS-7, it is showing the below message -
[Message from PHP Manager for IIS-7 Installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaUnT.jpg)

and if if I press 'Yes' it opens a browser like that -
[Opens browser only, no installation starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkHGa.jpg)

If I press 'No', it exits from Installation process.

Is there any version of PHP manager that supports 32-bit processor?

Comment: Did you download the x86 or the x64 version of phpmanager?

Comment: yes, I downloaded all possible and available(only four **_.exe_** files were there) options and nothing worked for me.

Comment: From where? Show me. Would try the x86 MSI installer found here: https://github.com/phpmanager/phpmanager/releases

Comment: You can download it from web platform installer. If it sill fail, I suggest you ask for help in this forums.https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/php-manager-for-iis

Comment: FWIW, there's no point in even trying 64-bit software on 32-bit operating systems. Albeit Intel-based, it's a different architecture, just like e.g. ARM.

Comment: Problem resolved....Thank you all for your suggestions and I express my whole hearted gratitude to all of you for your valuable time.

Comment: Please post your answer and mark it so that it can help others with similar problems.